# Is there a way to detect a C# 10 breaking change in the resolution for extension methods?

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

Consider the following code:

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.Method(()=>{});
    }
}

public sealed class Test
{
    public void Method(Delegate _)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test.Method(Delegate)");
    }
}

public static class TestExt
{
    public static void Method(this Test self, Action _)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestExt.Method(Action)");
    }
}
```

In C# 9.0 targeting `net48`, [this outputs `TestExt.Method(Action)`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VOucc2)

In C# 10.0 targeting `net6.0`, [this outputs `Test.Method(Delegate)`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W3sCRD)

Obviously this is a breaking change because the extension method may execute different code.

My question is: **Is there a way to detect this sort of breaking change in the code without inspecting all the code? For example, is there a code analysis rule that we can enable to detect this sort of code?**

This change has actually caused a genuine bug in our code base.

---

Note that this difference in behaviour is only occurring because of changes to the extension method resolution. If instead of an extension method, the method is in the `Test` class itself then both language versions call `Test.Method(Action)`:

```
static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.Method(()=>{});
    }
}

public sealed class Test
{
    public void Method(Delegate _)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test.Method(Delegate)"); // Not called by either version.
    }

    public void Method(Action _)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestExt.Method(Action)"); // Called by C#9 and C#10.
    }
}
```

---

Background information:

This breaking change has bitten us because we have (rightly or wrongly) an extension method for `Control.BeginInvoke()` along these lines (error handling omitted):

```
public static void BeginInvoke(this Control control, Action action)
{
    if (control.IsHandleCreated)
        tryBeginInvoke(control, action);
}
```

This is no longer called for code like:

```
this.BeginInvoke(() => someMenu.Visible = somethingIsAvailable());
```

Instead, [`Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-control-begininvoke(system-delegate)) is called, which omits the check for `control.IsHandleCreated` and the `tryBeginInvoke()` error handling method.

Comment: Don't know if you've thought of this, but if you do "Find all References" (on the extension method) in list view under both versions, you should have two text files you can quickly diff to find the missing calls.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately the extension method is in a separate solution (a class library that's used all over the place), so it won't find them. It's obvious now that we should never have given the extension method the same name as a the method in class Control, but it was written 10 years ago (to allow the use of Action without having to create a delegate at each call site) and someone extended its behaviour from just being a convenience method to actually doing some error handling...

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55319